# How to generate directory structure out of org-mode outline?

Tags: org-mode

I want to create the directory tree structure like this out of org-mode outlines.

> Dir1
>
> > - Dir-1.1
> >
> >   - Dir -1.1.1
> > - Dir-1.2
> >
> > Dir 2
> >
> > - Dir-2.1
> > - Dir-2.2

I am new to emacs and I have tried a few shell commands from here like

```
  xargs -d '\n' mkdir -p -- < test.txt
```

For that to work I need a file with the following structure.

```
# Test.txt
A1/A2/A3
B1/B2/B3
C1/C2/C3
```

TLDR: Generate Directory structure out of org outlines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org-element-parse-buffer` and `org-element-map` are your friends.
You get the doc strings of these two functions (and of every other function) by <kbd>C-h f</kbd>.

The following function `org-headlines-to-dir-tree` parses the org buffer via `org-element-parse-buffer` and creates the directories corresponding to the headlines via `org-element-map`.
This is pure Elisp. No shell commands are required.

```el
(defun org-headlines-to-dir-tree (dir &optional data)
  "Transform org headlines in DATA to directory tree below DIR.
DATA defaults to the headline structure of the current org buffer."
  (interactive "DTarget directory:")
  (unless data
    (unless (derived-mode-p 'org-mode)
      (user-error "%S is not an org buffer" (current-buffer)))
    (setq data (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline)))
  (unless (file-directory-p dir)
    (user-error "%S is not a directory" dir))
  (let ((default-directory (expand-file-name dir)))
    (org-element-map
        data
        'headline
      (lambda (el)
        (let ((title (org-element-property :title el))
              (contents (org-element-contents el)))
          (when (y-or-n-p (format "Create directory %S?" (expand-file-name title)))
            (mkdir title)
            (when contents
              (org-headlines-to-dir-tree title contents))))) ;; Recursion.
      nil ;; info
      nil ;; first match
      'headline ;; no-recursion (We do the recursion ourselves with additional directory changes.)
      )))
```

You can paste that stuff into your `*scratch*` buffer and evaluate it by placing point in to the function body and typing <kbd>C-M-x</kbd>.